# Join a signalr group in C# (.NET Client)

Tags: c#, signalr

Iv'e been going round in circles for the last 24 hours and it's driving me nuts. Basically all I want to do is join a signalr group using C# (.NET client). It just doesn't work. I Need help? I have all my apps using js and works perfect but I need to use C# for a specific task. Any help greatly appreciated:

The Hub:

```
[HubName("applicationHub")]
public class ApplicationHub : Hub
{
    public async Task JoinGroup(string group)
    {
        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
        string msg = "Hi " + "All";
        Clients.Group(group).testing(msg);
    }
  }
```

.NET Client Code: This should fire on page load of a webform

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:42700");
 IHubProxy applicationHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("applicationHub");
 hubConnection.Start().Wait();
 applicationHubProxy.Invoke("joinGroup", "RoomName");
```

The Front End should receive the message (in js):

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.url = "http://localhost:42700/signalr";

// Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
var applicationHub = connection.createHubProxy('applicationHub');

applicationHub.on('testing', function (msg)
{
     alert(msg);
});
```

**//EDIT**

I'm already calling: `connection.start();` forgot to add it to the Q.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll comment this time in case another missed point.  Have you added the front end client to the "RoomName" group?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to join the group from the client end. Basically I want to join via C#, sharp and notify all group users, that a user has connected. So the receiving js function "testing" should emit the message. (Apologies if I'm misunderstanding).

Comment: The 'testing' message only goes out to the group.  The front end client, not being a member of the group, will not receive the message.

Comment: So if I, in C# connect to a group (on page load), I also have to do the same in js(on page load)? for the exact same user(me). Seems a little odd.

Comment: Each connection is a different user as far as SignalR is concerned.

Comment: Ok, Well that makes sense...Never ran into this issue before. So is there away to join a group in C# and emit the message to the front-end, without joining the group again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78460/discussion-between-steve-mitcham-and-tez-wingfield).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your testing message is only going out to members of the group,  either add the front end client to the group, or change the group join call to

```
Clients.All.testing(msg);
```